# partial differential equations , first order help

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the linear first order non-homogeneous partial differential equation

> $U_x+yU_y-y=ye^{-x}$
>
> By using the method of characteristics show that its general
>   solution is given by $u(x,y)=-ye^{-x}+e^xg(ye^{-x})$
>
> where $g$ is any differentiable function of its argument

$A=1$ , $B=y$ , $d=-1$ , $f=ye^{-x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{b}{a}=y$

$dy=y~dx$

$\int\dfrac{1}{y}dy=\int dx$

$\ln y=x+c$

$\eta(x,y)=c$

let $\xi=x$

Then

$\eta=\ln y-x$

$\xi=x$

those are my characteristics curves,

when I put it into $[a\xi_x+b\xi_y]\omega_\xi+d\omega=F$

I get the equation $\omega_\xi-\omega=e^\eta$

Is this all correct?

Answer (score 0):

$U_x+yU_y-y=ye^{-x}$

$U_x+yU_y=y(e^{-x}+1)$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0e^x$

$\dfrac{dU}{dt}=y(e^{-x}+1)=y_0(e^t+1)$ , we have $U(x,y)=y_0(e^t+t)+g(y_0)=y(xe^{-x}+1)+g(ye^{-x})$